# Simple form validation

Tags: validation, coffeescript

I would really like to hear how I can improve my form validator. Next, I want to refactor it into OO and learn a testing framework like Jasmine.

Some things I know I could improve:

- Don't make it tied to the DOM as much (using `parent().parent()`, for ex.).
- Combined validations can't be used. For example, using `isBlank` and `isInteger` will not validate properly because if `isInteger` fails, it throws an error and `isBlank` passes and clears *all* errors.
- Make a config object to update with custom error messages.
- Possibly make a jQuery plugin so passing the object to validate is easier.

[Github repo](http://bit.ly/SUIvOC)

```
  jQuery -> # on Document ready

    errorCount = null

    valEl = $('.validate')  # cache .validate elements
    submitBtn = valEl.parent().parent().find('input[type=submit]')

    valEl.on "blur", ->
      input = $(this)
      validate(input)

    validate = (input) ->
      inputVal = input.val()
      inputLen = inputVal.length
      validations = input.data()         #cache data-xxx tags

      if validations.notblank is on
        if inputLen <= 0
          throwError("This field can't be blank", input)
        else
          removeError(input)

      if validations.minchars > 0
        if inputLen < validations.minchars
          throwError("You need at least 5 chars", input)
        else
          removeError(input)

      if validations.isinteger is on
        isInteger = /^\d+$/
        if isInteger.test(inputVal) is false
          throwError("Must be a whole number", input)
        else
          removeError(input)

    throwError = (message, input) ->
      if !input.hasClass('has-error')
        errorCount += 1
        input.addClass "has-error"
        input.nextAll('.errorContainer').append(message)

    removeError = (input) ->
      if input.hasClass('has-error')
        errorCount -= 1
        input.removeClass("has-error")
        input.nextAll('.errorContainer').empty()

    submitBtn.on "click", (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      if errorCount is 0
        valEl.parent().parent().submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could break out your validation functions into a separate object, like so:

```
validators =
  isinteger: (input) ->
    # check that value is an int

  notblank: (input) ->
    # check that value is present
```

These functions could return a simple boolean, or they could return an error message if validation fails and `null` if it passes.

The point is that you keep the functions separate, so they're easier to manage and customize. But it also means that you can give your inputs data attributes like `data-validator` which simply is the name of the validation method to use. So you can say, for example

```
method = $(input).data "validator"
result = validators[method]?(input)
```

With a little string-splitting, you could make the field plural, like `data-validators="isinteger, notblank"`, and check each.

You could also make the error-throwing into an event you can listen for elsewhere. Then you avoid having your error presentation mixed up with your validations, and you don't have to rely on a predefined `.errorContainer` element. For instance:

```
throwError = (message, input) ->
  $(input).trigger 'validation:error', message

# ... elsewhere ...

$(document).on 'validation:error', 'input', (event) ->
  # handle error event
```

---

Other stuff I noticed:

1. Don't bind to the submit button's `click` event! Forms can also be submitted by simply pressing enter/return, without ever clicking the submit button. Instead, bind the form element's `submit` event which is fired regardless of how the form is submitted, and use `preventDefault()` to stop the submission if necessary.
2. Your `notblank` logic won't complain if the user just enters some space characters. In most cases the field should probably be considered blank, if it only contains whitespace. So use `$.trim()` on the value first, to trim off leading and trailing whitespace.
3. HTML5 has a `required` attribute you can add to inputs - no need to have your own syntax for say an input should be `notblank`. Check for the `required` attribute instead (`if $(input).attr('required') ...`). It makes the HTML more semantically correct.

---

I don't know if you already have solutions for the specific things you mention, but here are my ideas:

- You can use `.closest("form")` to find the form element instead of `parent().parent()`
- If you store all validation failures in an array, you just need to check the array's length, to see if the were any errors. Multiple validations won't override each other, and you don't need `errorCount`

Comment: Wow thanks! I can't wait to start refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could consider doing is following the approach set out by @Flambino with different `Validator` objects. You could start with a `ValidatorBase` object that you can decorate with additional methods or even override existing methods with new definitions (see Javascript Decorator pattern at: http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-design-patterns-decorator/).

Here's a really crude/untested example of what I'm getting at:

```
var ValidatorBase = function() {
    console.log('Booya baby1');
}

ValidatorBase.prototype = {
    validate: function() {
        console.log('ValidatorBase::validate()');
    }
}

ValidatorDecorator = function( objValidator ){
    this.validator = objValidator;

}

ValidatorDecorator.prototype = {
    validate: function( objElement ) {
        console.log('ValidatorDecorator::validate()');
        return ( objElement && objElement.value !=  '' );
    }
}

DateValidator = function( objValidator ){
    ValidatorDecorator.call( this, objValidator );
}

DateValidator.prototype = new ValidatorDecorator();
DateValidator.prototype.checkDate = function( date ) {
    return date.match(/^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\- \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\- \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/);
}
DateValidator.prototype.validate = function( objElement ) {
    console.log('DateValidator::validate()');
    return (/* validation logic, returns True|False*/ this.validator.validate( objElement ) && ( this.checkDate( objElement.value ) ) );
}
```

Personally, I'd refactor this and wrap it into a module or plugin (same thing in jQuery land.)

This approach let's you take advantage of jQuery's event bindings while providing you with the ability to consistently apply different types of validators to the types of elements/data you want to validate. You may still want to map fields to validators types, or use the data-attribute, e.g. `<input type="text" data-validator-type="DateValidator" />` to specify which validator gets applied (this can be done in a single validate() method or you can handle it during serialization of your data if you're using AJAX... or hook the submit event on your form.)

Comment: Cool, i'll have to read up on the decorator pattern!